# Premier inn old Trafford to Manchester airport

Tags: uk, airport-transfer, manchester

I need to get from premier inn at old Trafford to Manchester airport for a flight at 8.30 Saturday morning. Quite a while since I’ve used the trams in Manchester. I will have a rucksack. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Manchester has the usual mix of public transport options with timetables and phone numbers available on the web. What do you need from us?

Comment: @Chrissie Hall Have you checked whether your hotel offers an airport shuttle service? There’d be a fee but probably quite small and worth it for less hassle

Comment: International or domestic flight? How long before flights do you like to arrive?

Comment: @ReddHerring Plus the fact that services such as Google Maps will tell you exactly how to get from A to B by public transport.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're asking for directions, here's the map for the TFGM Tram system:
https://tfgm.com/public-transport/tram/network-map

If you have the time and want to only tram it, you'll want to take the tram from Old Trafford to Trafford Bar (Frequency every 12 minutes, journey time 2 mins) where you can then pick up the Manchester Airport line (Frequency every 12 minutes, journey time 42 minutes from Trafford Bar).

This is going to make it a rough 1 hour journey and the earliest you can get from Old Trafford to Trafford bar is on the 06:04 from Altrincham - I'd expect it'll reach Old Trafford by 06:25. I wouldn't see you making Manchester Airport before 07:30 at the earliest if you do this.

Shown here though: https://tfgm.com/public-transport/tram/stops/trafford-bar-tram/tram-times/manchester-airport-tram#tram-times-panel you can get a Trafford Bar to Manchester Airport tram every 12 minutes from 03:12 [and you can walk to Trafford Bar Tram Stop from Old Trafford Tram Stop in approx 12 minutes](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Trafford+Bar+Tram+Station,+Seymour+Grove,+Stretford,+Manchester/Old+Trafford,+Stretford,+Manchester+M16+9AL/@53.4586702,-2.2912043,15.25z/data=!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x487bae0f5c315897:0x506b57a288204a2f!2m2!1d-2.2775001!2d53.4616846!1m5!1m1!1s0x487bae0a6660906d:0x7ce6dbad13a7f3ff!2m2!1d-2.284966!2d53.45636!3e2).

Depending on when you want to check-in then (and working backwards from that point), Pick your suitable check-in time, budget an hour into getting the Tram from Trafford Bar to Manchester Airport, and another 15-20 mins walk from the Travellodge to Trafford Bar (and maybe a little extra tolerance for the unexpected). That will give you your set off time.